# How do you solve the equation $2^{|x+1|}-|2^x-1| = 2^x+1$?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

| ... | is absolute value
$2^{|x+1|}-|2^x-1| = 2^x+1$, move $|2^x-1|$ to RHS: $2^{|x+1|} = 2^x+1+|2^x-1|$
Log base 2 each side:
$|x+1| = log_2 (2^x+1+|2^x-1|)$
Here we quickly observe: $-1$ is not a solution but $0$ is a solution. If you try negative numbers $-2$ is also a solution.

How do I find the value of $x$ (not intuitively like I did previously) for which the equation is true?

Thanks in advance for any help.

edit: Solved, thanks to all who replied. Split $2^{|x+1|} = 2^x+1+|2^x-1|$ into three cases: $x >= 0$ and $x < -1$ and $-1 <= x < 0$. Solution: $[0, \infty]$ ∪ ${-2}$

Comment: A common method to solve equations with absolute values is to solve by cases. You can observe that, for instance, if $x\geq 0$ that the equation becomes $2^{x+1}=2^x+1+2^{x}-1$.  Can you proceed from this?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski In my case: x>=0 gives an infinite amount of solutions [0, +inf). 
For x < 0 I will have: 2^(-x-1) = 2^x+1 + 1 - 2^x then the only solution is -2. And I just calculate the union of the 2 sets (or whatever the correct English word is) to get [0, +inf) ∪ {-2}. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good work! You got the correct solutions, but you have missed one case namely the one $-1\leq x < 0$.

Comment: Whoops, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For $x\geq0$ the equation becomes
$$2^{x+1}-(2^x-1)=2^x+1$$
and the left hand side simplifies to $2^x+1$ so that every $x\geq 0$ is a solution.

For $x<0$ the equation becomes
$$2^{|x+1|}+(2^x-1)=2^x+1$$
so we get $2^{|x+1|}=2$ so that $|x+1|=1$ so that $x=-2$ is another solution.

Comment: There is one solution for x<0 (x = -2), you accidentally put a "+" instead of a "-" in the LHS. Thank you very much for guiding me either way, didn't think of splitting the problem into 2 cases.

Comment: @cezar You're welcome. You're right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If $|x+1|\ge 0$ the equation becomes
$$
2\cdot 2^x-|2^x-1|=2^x+1
$$
that is equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
2^x-1\ge0\\
2\cdot 2^x-2^x+1=2^x+1
\end{cases}
\quad \lor\quad
\begin{cases}
2^x-1<0\\
2\cdot 2^x+2^x-1=2^x+1
\end{cases}
$$
can you solve these two systems? and solve also the other case: for $|x+1|< 0$ ?